# Handle different configuration files on cloned containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to spawn 2 containers based on the same source code but with different configuration files.

The first prerequisit is that the two instances have to modify their configuration files (from the docker-entrypoint.sh ATM) but **MUST NOT** impact each other or the host.

The second prerequisit (and where I am stuck) is that I also want changes to the source code on the host be mirrored on the containers to avoid rebuilding them every time a change is made.
I thought I could create a tmpfs volume to allow containers to manage their own configuration easily and not persist it but this feature does not seem available on Windows and several members of my team are using that OS.

Anyone got an idea to make this work ? If it is of any use, the goal is to allow developers to easily work on this project without the hassle of building the corresponding architecture (2 instances communicating with each other over a network that allows one-way flow only, using RMQ).

> docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "2.4"

networks:
    gateway_network:
        name: "gateway_network"

volumes:
    gateway_data:
        name: "gateway_data"

services:
    rabbitmq:
        container_name: "rmq"
        image: "rabbitmq:3.7"
        expose:
            - "5672"

    php_internal:
        container_name: "php-int"
        build: "."
        networks:
          - "gateway_network"
        environment:
            - "APP_ENV=dev"
            - "GW_TYPE=internal"
        volumes:
            - "gateway_data:/data/ssl"
            - ".:/www"
        expose:
            - "9000"
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq

    php_external:
        container_name: "php-ext"
        build: "."
        networks:
            - "gateway_network"
        environment:
            - "APP_ENV=dev"
            - "GW_TYPE=external"
        volumes:
            - "gateway_data:/data/ssl"
            - ".:/www"
        expose:
            - "9000"
        depends_on:
            - php_internal
        restart: always

    web_internal:
        container_name: "gw-int"
        image: "nginx:latest"
        networks:
            - "gateway_network"
        ports:
            - "8000:443"
        volumes:
            - ".:/www"
            - "./docker/nginx/internal.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "gateway_data:/data/ssl"
        depends_on:
            - php_internal
        restart: always

    web_external:
        container_name: "gw-ext"
        image: "nginx:latest"
        networks:
            - "gateway_network"
        ports:
            - "8001:443"
        volumes:
            - ".:/www"
            - "./docker/nginx/external.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "gateway_data:/data/ssl"
        depends_on:
            - php_external
        restart: always
```

> Dockerfile

```
# See https://hub.docker.com/_/php/#how-to-use-this-image
# See https://github.com/TrafeX/docker-php-nginx/

ARG PHP_VERSION=7.1

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine
# Use "latest" to get the most recent version of composer

RUN set -eux; apk --no-cache --update add \
    acl curl libgd freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libpng-dev bzip2-dev libxml2-dev curl-dev icu-dev \
    openldap-dev imap-dev sqlite-dev git \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd intl bcmath bz2 ldap pdo_mysql

RUN set -eux; CFLAGS="-I/usr/src/php" docker-php-ext-install xmlreader
RUN set -eux; docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap pcntl sockets

COPY --from=composer:1.8.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

COPY ./docker/fpm/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./docker/php/custom_php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/custom_php.ini

VOLUME [ "/www/var", "/data/ssl" ]
COPY ./app/config/parameters.yml.dist /www/app/config/parameters.yml

WORKDIR /www

COPY ./docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

> docker-entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php-fpm "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'php-fpm' ] || [ "$1" = 'php' ] || [ "$1" = 'bin/console' ]; then
    rm -rf var/cache var/log
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log
    setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX var
    setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX var

    setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX /var
    setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX /var

    if [ "$GW_TYPE" = 'internal' ]; then
        # Generate cert for the internal gateway to authenticate itself
        openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out /data/ssl/private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
        openssl rsa -pubout -in /data/ssl/private_key.pem -out /data/ssl/public_key.pem

        # Generate self-signed HTTPS cert for nginx instances
        openssl genrsa -out /data/ssl/webserver_ca.key 4096
        openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key /data/ssl/webserver_ca.key -out /data/ssl/webserver_ca.crt -subj "some_subject"

        openssl genrsa -out /data/ssl/webserver.key 4096
        openssl req -new -key /data/ssl/webserver.key -out /data/ssl/webserver.csr -subj "some_subject"
        openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in /data/ssl/webserver.csr -CA /data/ssl/webserver_ca.crt -CAkey /data/ssl/webserver_ca.key -set_serial 01 -out /data/ssl/webserver.crt


        openssl genrsa -out /data/ssl/client.key 4096
        openssl req -new -key /data/ssl/client.key -out /data/ssl/client.csr -subj "some_subject"
        openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in /data/ssl/client.csr -CA /data/ssl/webserver_ca.crt -CAkey /data/ssl/webserver_ca.key -set_serial 01 -out /data/ssl/client.crt
    fi

    if [ "$APP_ENV" != 'prod' ]; then
        composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction
    fi

    echo "Starting..."
fi

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

Comment: Use a docker-compose.override.yml file? More info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files. If this solves your problem I can write an answer with more information.

Comment: If I correctly understand what I'm reading that should do the trick yes ! Writing a complete answer would be neat :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Docker Compose you can create and destroy isolated environments very easily in a few commands from your command prompt or scripts, like the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-test.override.yml up -d
```

You should use multiple compose files. This lets you create multiple configuration variants depending on the environment.

**Overriding the base docker-compose file**

A typical use case is when you define multiple compose files so you can target multiple environments, like production, staging, CI, or development. To support these differences, you can split your Compose configuration into multiple files like `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose.prod.yml`, `docker-compose.staging.yml`.

In the base `docker-compose.yml` file, you just want to set the information that is common across environments. Then in the `docker-compose.override.yml` or similar files for production or staging, you should place configuration that is specific for each environment.

See this image as illustration:
[image]

Source:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files
- https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/multi-container-applications-docker-compose.md#using-multiple-docker-compose-files-to-handle-several-environments
- eBook [.NET Microservices: Architecture for Containerized .NET Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/)